# How to remove unchecked value from checkbox

Tags: jquery, laravel

Hi i have problem when unchecked value from multiple checkbox

when i unchecked one of checkbox from multiple checkbox from looping / foreach value from checkbox still show / not remove when submit to controller

Example when i unchecked value G000, value G000 still show / not remove

Here is my code

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('title', 'Edit User Module')

@push('style')
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.shieldui.com/shared/components/latest/css/light-bootstrap/all.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css">
@endpush

@section('content')
<div class="card">
    <form action="{{ route('module-users.update.route', $user_id) }}" method="POST">
        @csrf

        <div class="card-header">Edit User Module</div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                    <ul id="treeview">
                        @foreach ($parent_menus as $parent_menu)
                            {{-- <li data-expanded="true">{{ $parent_menu->Description }} {{ $parent_menu->ModuleID }} --}}
                            <li>{{ $parent_menu->Description }} {{ $parent_menu->ModuleID }}
                                <input type="checkbox" name="menus_id[]" class="pc-box"
                                    value="{{ $parent_menu->ModuleID }}" onclick="check_parent(this)"
                                    {{ in_array(trim($parent_menu->ModuleID), $all_modules) ? 'checked' : '' }}
                                    {{-- onclick="$(this).val(this.checked ? '{{ $parent_menu->ModuleID }}' : 0);" --}}
                                    >
                                <ul>
                                    @foreach ($child_menus1 as $child_menu1)
                                        @if ($parent_menu->ModuleID == $child_menu1->HeaderId)
                                            <li data-expanded="true">{{ $child_menu1->Description }} {{ $child_menu1->ModuleID }}
                                                <input type="checkbox" name="menus_id[]" value="{{ $child_menu1->ModuleID }}"
                                                    class="cc-box-{{ $parent_menu->ModuleID }}"
                                                    {{ in_array(trim($child_menu1->ModuleID), $all_modules) ? 'checked' : '' }}
                                                    {{-- onclick="$(this).val(this.checked ? '{{ $child_menu1->ModuleID }}' : 0);" --}}
                                                    >
                                                <ul>
                                                    @foreach ($child_menus2 as $child_menu2)
                                                        @if ($child_menu1->ModuleID == $child_menu2->HeaderId)
                                                            <li>{{ $child_menu2->Description }} {{ $child_menu2->ModuleID }}
                                                                <input type="checkbox" name="menus_id[]" value="{{ $child_menu2->ModuleID }}"
                                                                    class="cc-box-{{ $parent_menu->ModuleID }}"
                                                                    {{ in_array(trim($child_menu2->ModuleID), $all_modules) ? 'checked' : '' }}
                                                                    {{-- onclick="$(this).val(this.checked ? '{{ $child_menu1->ModuleID }}' : 0);" --}}
                                                                    >
                                                            </li>
                                                        @endif
                                                    @endforeach
                                                </ul>
                                            </li>
                                        @endif
                                    @endforeach
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        @endforeach
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

            <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{ $user_id }}">
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
@endsection

@push('script')
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.shieldui.com/shared/components/latest/js/shieldui-all.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function ($) {
        $("#treeview").shieldTreeView();
    });

    $(function() {
        $('.attribute').click(function() {
            alert($(this).val() + ' ' + (this.checked ? 'checked' : 'unchecked'));
        });
    });

    function check_parent(e){
        $(".cc-box-"+e.value).attr("checked", "true");
    }
</script>
@endpush
```

And here is my update method from controller

```
public function update_route(Request $request, $user_id)
    {
        $user_id = $request->user_id;
        $menus_id = $request->menus_id;
        $menus = array_unique($menus_id);

        foreach ($menus as $menu) {
            $check = DB::table('usermodules')
                    ->where('moduleid', $menu)
                    ->where('userid', 'temmy')
                    ->exists();

            if(!$check)
            {
                UserModule::create([
                    'userid' => 'temmy',
                    'moduleid' => $menu,
                    'r_read' => '1',
                    'r_edit' => '1',
                    'r_delete' => '1',
                    'fou' => '1',
                    'fop' => '1',
                    'fod' => '1',
                ]);
            }else{
                DB::table('usermodules')->where('userid', 'temmy')->delete();
                UserModule::create([
                    'userid' => 'temmy',
                    'moduleid' => $menu,
                    'r_read' => '1',
                    'r_edit' => '1',
                    'r_delete' => '1',
                    'fou' => '1',
                    'fop' => '1',
                    'fod' => '1',
                ]);
            }
        }

        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

Here is my UserModule

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class UserModule extends Model
{
    // Custom set name table
    protected $table = 'usermodules';
    // Custon set primary key name
    protected $primaryKey = 'userid';
    // Off created_at and updated_at built in
    public $timestamps = false;
    // Off incrementing built in
    public $incrementing = false;

    protected $fillable = ['userid', 'moduleid', 'r_read', 'r_edit', 'r_delete', 'fou', 'fop', 'fod'];
}
```

Any solution of this problem?

Thanks

[UI Screen Shot[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpNsV.png)

Comment: put your UserModule model

Comment: I see  no code that attempts to uncheck the checkbox here. It may be hiding somewhere but you really need to write a more focused question if that's the case.

Comment: @apokryfos Do you have any solution from this case?

Comment: That might be because your checkbox might be styled and overlayed by CSS and span or so. So when you check/uncheck because of CSS it mimics to be unchecked or checked, but in reality, it doesn't. This is just my guess, a better picture would be available if you inspect element and check.

Comment: No, I'm just not sure I have actually understood where the problem is. Can you edit the code to make it cleaner and clearer?

Comment: change this function "check_parent". to check and uncheck the check box according to current status. your method always checks the check box when click on a check box. also remove the commented line using blade template comments.

Comment: @GauravRai Hi thanks about your advice, the problem already solved

my library tree view create 2 layer, i change my jquery treeview to another library